# Docker container unable to comunicate with MySQL command line

Tags: mysql, linux, docker

I'm trying to install MySQL using a Dockerfile based on ubuntu. Before you say something: **please, don't tell me to use a mysql image because I need to do it this way.**

Edit: when I get into the container and execute mysql -u root it works perfectly. It's just that I can't do it though the dockerfile.

This is the Dockerfile code:

```
    FROM ubuntu:latest
    RUN apt update \ 
    && apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common libmysqlclient-dev -y 
    RUN usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql 
    RUN service mysql start 
    RUN mysql -u root
    RUN SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user \ 
    && ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password' \ 
    && FLUSH PRIVILEGES \ 
    && exit
```

But I get this message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I also get these during the build, which seems a bit suspicious and might be related to the issue, so I let it here just in case it's helpful.

```
    debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
    debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
    debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
    invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
    invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
    update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
    Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/0: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/1: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/2: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/3: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/4: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/5: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/6: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/7: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/8: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/9: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/10: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/11: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/12: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/13: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/14: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/15: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/16: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/17: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/18: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/19: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/20: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/21: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/22: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/23: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/24: Permission denied
    Cannot stat file /proc/225/fd/25: Permission denied
    mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
    mysqld is running as pid 883
    invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
    invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
```

Comment: A Docker image never contains running processes; if you start mysqld in a `RUN` command it won't be running during the next `RUN` command.  To a first approximation `service` just doesn't work in Docker and you should avoid it.  You might look at the entrypoint script for the Docker Hub `mysql` image; it has a complicated sequence that starts the database so it can run first-time setup scripts, but that's approximately what you need to replicate.