# docker ubuntu container install mysql-server always stuck in "Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/0: Permission denied"

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

I find [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69572144/docker-container-unable-to-comunicate-with-mysql-command-line) but not answer fix my bug

how to reproduce

when init ubuntu:22.04 container without any modification

run `docker exec test-ubuntu bash -c "apt update; apt install mysql-server"`

mysql stuck in "Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)"

full output:

```
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/0: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/1: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/2: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/3: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/4: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/5: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/6: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/7: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/8: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/9: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/10: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/11: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/12: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/13: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/14: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/15: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/16: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/17: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/18: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/19: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/20: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/21: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/22: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/23: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/24: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/433/fd/25: Permission denied
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 1030
Error: Unable to shut down server with process id 1030
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Setting up libclone-perl (0.45-1build3) ...
Setting up libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Setting up liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Setting up libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1.1) ...
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl:amd64 (3.76-1build2) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.36-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when i run `docker exec test-ubuntu bash -c 'cat /var/log/mysql/error.log'`, cannot find any error

```
2023-02-16T03:25:14.092640Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) initializing of server in progress as process 980
2023-02-16T03:25:14.099155Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-02-16T03:25:15.437369Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-02-16T03:25:19.676899Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2023-02-16T03:25:23.597131Z 6 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2).
2023-02-16T03:25:29.456978Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1028
2023-02-16T03:25:29.470270Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-02-16T03:25:29.724484Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-02-16T03:25:30.124681Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-02-16T03:25:30.124748Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-02-16T03:25:30.129841Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2023-02-16T03:25:30.147250Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-02-16T03:25:30.147299Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.c4bayLhPNX/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2023-02-16T03:25:30.175862Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2).
2023-02-16T03:25:31.861822Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
```

Comment: You're doing this in a temporary container; anything you do in this `docker exec` shell will be lost as soon as the container exits.  I'd suggest avoiding `docker exec` in most cases and doing these steps in a reproducible Dockerfile instead.  You also could use the [Docker Hub `mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) instead of trying to create your own database-server container setup.